# Is there a way to write a generic function that will extend an entity by an array in rust?

Tags: rust

My goal is to write a function that looks like this:

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Q{}

fn extending_function<A: Extend<Q>>(out: &mut A) {
   let p = Q{};
   out.extend(&[p]);
}
```

`Vec` impls `Extend`, so since I can write the following code:

```rust
fn extending_function_vec(out: &mut Vec<Q>) {
   let p = Q{};
   out.extend(vec![p].into_iter());
}
```

or

```rust
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct Q{}
fn extending_function_vec(out: &mut Vec<Q>) {
   let p = Q{};
   out.extend(&[p]);
}
```

Although here too, I have a small issue: *Either* Q has to be Copy or I have to stick it into a `vec`.

But when I try to genericize it, the only way I could get it to work is to make my code look like this:

```rust
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct Q{}

fn extending_function<A: Extend<Q>>(out: &mut A) {
   let p = Q{};
   out.extend(vec![p].into_iter());
}
```

Where I have to *both* use a `vec` *and* make Q copy.

The issue is:

1. `Q` must be `Copy`. Even if I try `out.extend(vec![Q{}].into_iter().cloned());`, I get a syntax error.
2. I have to put it into a `vec`. Is there a way to extend from a static array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Extend` trait lets you pass in any type that implements `IntoIterator` (including any iterator).

The simplest iterator for a single value is `std::iter::once(value)`, which will yield that value exactly once. It will also move the value (like `Vec::into_iter` does), so you don't need for the type to be `Copy` or `Clone`. So the simplest way to extend with a single value is:

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Q{}

fn extending_function<A: Extend<Q>>(out: &mut A) {
   let p = Q{};
   out.extend(std::iter::once(p));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, But how can I turn an array into an iterator?

Comment: That's not possible, as arrays to do implement the `IntoIterator` trait, like `Vec` does. So if you need to extend by exactly one value (like in your example), `std::iter::once` is probably best, otherwise if you don't already have an iterator you can use it's probably easiest to just use `Vec`.